# Summation and Matrix Operations

Tags: matrices, summation

[image]

Hi, I understand how to compute X'X, but I am not sure how the computation using the summation should be achieved?

X' =  \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 3 \\
2 & -4 \\
\end{array}

so, X'X = \begin{array}{ccc}
10 & -10 \\
-10 & 20 \\
\end{array}

But using summation, wouldnt you only get two values? [1 2] * [1 2]' and [3 -4] * [3 -4]' ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I see how you may get confused with the wording of the problem.

$x_i$ is *not* a row vector, they mean the column vector formed by the components of the $i$th row of $X$.

Then

$$
\sum^2_{i = 1} x_i x_i' = 
\begin{bmatrix}
       1 \\
       2
     \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
       1 & 2
     \end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
       3 \\
       -4
     \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
       3 & -4
     \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
       1 & 2 \\
       2 & 4
     \end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
       9 & -12 \\
       -12 & 16
     \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
       10 & -10 \\
       -10 & 20
     \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much! @AdamFrancey